# Tochscreen supported Remote Desktop Protokoll

Tags: wpf, terminal, rdp

i have one Problem. We developed an application, witch runs on a terminalserver.
On these terminalserver are multiple sessions.

If i want to use the application from an Machine we have an remote desktop session to the terminal server.

That all works.

But i want to use the Scroll gesture from the touchscreen in my WPF application.

any ideas how to give the events from the Touchscreen to the rdp session?

best Regards

Comment: WPF is not intended to be used via remote desktop. Have your users install the client application on their computers, and forget this remote desktop hack.

Comment: is that your own opinion?? That doesent Help.